# Problemas con el lenguaje y localizacion al utilizar rtweet para la recogida de tweets usando google API key

Tags: r

Estoy intentando recopilar tweets mediante la utilización de una función de rtweet llamada search_tweets. El caso es que cuando utilizo "usa" dentro de geocode, el código me devuelve un df con los datos adecuados. Sin embargo, cuando utilizo otro país, por ejemplo "france", me devuelve un df con 0 observaciones.

```
library(rtweet)

# Twitter API
create_token(
  app = "my_api",
  consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  access_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)

# Google Maps API 
apiKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

#Collection
df<-search_tweets(q = "word",
                               retryonratelimit = T, lang = "en",
                               geocode = lookup_coords("usa", apikey = apiKey),
                               include_rts = FALSE, n = 100)
```

Por ejemplo, he intetnado recuperar tweets usando `q="et"`, `lang="fr"` y `geocode = lookup_coords("france",apikey=apikey)` y la salida fue, como decía, un df con 0 observaciones.

Adicionalmente, cuando utilizo "usa" y el código genera un df con tatos, resulta que contiene cerca de 18000 observaciones, a pesar de haber limitado `n = 100`. No entiendo bien qué está pasando.

Si alguien me echa un cable lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente, no tengo una API Key de Google para probar `lookup_coords()`, sin embargo, revisando la documentación de la [API de twiter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), en el caso de la geolocalización, una de las cosas que dice:

> The parameter value is specified by " latitude,longitude,radius ",
>   where radius units must be specified as either " mi " (miles) or " km
>   " (kilometers).

Podemos usar la geolocalización de **Google**  o bien podemos usar una cadena formateada tal como espera **twiter**, por ejemplo, para ver los tweets de Paris en un radio de 5 kilómetros, solo tenemos que buscar [latitud y longitud](https://www.antipodas.net/coordenadaspais/francia/paris.php) y construir nuestro `geocode`:

```
geocode <-  "48.8534,2.3486,5km"

df <- search_tweets(q = "et", 
                    lang = "fr",
                    retryonratelimit = FALSE, 
                    geocode = geocode,
                    include_rts = FALSE, 
                    n = 100)

df %>% nrow()
df$text[1]

[1] 100

[1] "Donc il y a une version d'Oceania de Björk en duo avec Kelis et je découvre ca que maintenant... qui suis-je \n\nhttps://t.co/mfGplVzpsu"
```

Esto como verás ha funcionado bien, por lo que deberías revisar el código generado por `lookup_coords()` y ver que es lo que pasa, o bien establecer manualmente este dato como en el ejemplo que doy.

Con respecto a lo que comentas acerca del limite `n`, el mismo solo es válido cuando además has indicado `retryonratelimit = FALSE`

Comment: Gracias. Siempre buenas respuestas.